# Wireshark in windows 10 not showing "80211" header for Link Layer Header column

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing, 802.11

I am trying to capture Wi-Fi frames and check few parameters of 802.11. For that, I was trying to set the `Link Layer Header` of `Capture Options` in the wire shark. The drop down of the Interface WiFi is showing only `Ethernet` and `DOCSIS` not 80211. Is there anything else I can check on?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for Wi-Fi interfaces – they are required to present an 802.3-compatible link layer, so the OS will convert 802.11 'Data' frames to Ethernet II frames and back.

Real 802.11 frames can only be captured in "Monitor" mode:

- https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Windows